# Successfully established hybrid connection loses connection after 20 minutes (restart of azure hybrid connection service requiered)

Tags: azure, biztalk, servicebus

I have a little problem while using hybrid connections in Azure to connect a local resource. I installed the connection manager successfully and established a connection to the on premise resource, everything works fine...

But after around 20 minutes the connection gets lost until I restart the azure hybrid connection service on the on premise server.

The AppService is connected to more than one server and all other connections work well. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem and establish a stable connection?

Comment: Do you have Always On enabled on the App Service?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered similar issues with Azure endpoints.  We resolved it by having a scheduled message sent to the local BizTalk web services every 3 minutes to keep it alive.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue - can you provide some specifics on how you setup the "keep-alive" scheduled message for BizTalk?

Comment: @BenM Hi Ben, you can do it various ways.  You can use a Schedule Adapter or scheduled task to create a message then then gets picked up by a send port that sends it to your local URI.